Variation of nonminimal derivative coupling term
all. Can I request you assistance about the following problem?
How do I vary this action with respect to metric $\delta g_{ab}$
$$
\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \Big[\kappa R+ G_{ab}\nabla^a \phi \nabla^b \phi \Big] \tag{1}
$$
to get (equation (5) from this reference)
$$
\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \Big[ \kappa G_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}\nabla_a\phi\nabla_b\phi R
+\nabla_c\phi\nabla_a\phi R_b^c
+\nabla_c\phi\nabla_b\phi R_a^c
+\nabla^c\phi\nabla^d\phi R_{acbd}
+(\nabla_a\nabla^c\phi)(\nabla_b\nabla_c\phi)
-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}(\nabla^c\nabla^d\phi)(\nabla_c\nabla_d\phi)
+\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}(\nabla^c\nabla_c\phi)^{2}
-(\nabla_a\nabla_b\phi)\nabla^c\nabla_c\phi
-\frac{1}{2}G_{ab}\nabla^c\phi\nabla_c\phi
-g_{ab}R^{cd}\nabla_c\phi\nabla_d\phi 
\Big] ?
\tag{2}
$$
I already get the first term in Eq. (2), however my calculation from the second term in Eq. (1) gives
\begin{align*}
\delta\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \Big[G_{ab}\nabla^a \phi \nabla^b \phi \Big] = 
\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \Big[ &
-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab} G_{cd} \nabla^c \phi \nabla^d\phi~ \delta g^{ab}
-\frac{1}{2}R\nabla_a \phi \nabla_b \phi ~\delta g^{ab}\\
&-\frac{1}{2} \nabla^c \phi \nabla_c \phi ~\delta R
+\nabla^a \phi \nabla^b \phi~\delta R_{ab}\Big]
\end{align*}
where in the last two terms become
\begin{align*}
-\sqrt{-g}\frac{1}{2} \nabla^c \phi \nabla_c \phi ~\delta R=&
-\sqrt{-g}\frac{1}{2} \nabla^c \phi \nabla_c \phi ~(R_{ab}+g_{ab}\nabla_e\nabla^e-\nabla_a\nabla_b) \delta g^{ab}\\
=& -\sqrt{-g}\frac{1}{2} \Big( R_{ab}\nabla^c\phi\nabla_c\phi +g_{ab}\nabla_e\nabla^e(\nabla^c\phi \nabla_c\phi) +\nabla_a\nabla_b(\nabla^c \phi \nabla_c)\Big)\delta g^{ab}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{-g}\nabla^a \phi \nabla^b \phi~\delta R_{ab}=&
\sqrt{-g}\nabla^a \phi \nabla^b \phi~\frac{1}{2}  \Big(
-g_{eb}\nabla_f\nabla_a 
-g_{ea}\nabla_f\nabla_b 
+g_{ae}g_{bf} \nabla_h\nabla^h 
+g_{ef}\nabla_a\nabla_b 
\Big)\delta g^{ef}\\
=& \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}  \Big\{
-g_{eb}\nabla_f\nabla_a (\nabla^a \phi \nabla^b \phi)
-g_{ea}\nabla_f\nabla_b (\nabla^a \phi \nabla^b \phi)
\\&
+g_{ae}g_{bf} \nabla_h\nabla^h (\nabla^a \phi \nabla^b \phi)
+g_{ef}\nabla_a\nabla_b (\nabla^a \phi \nabla^b \phi)
\Big\} \delta g^{ef}
\\
=& \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}  \Big\{
-g_{eb} (\nabla_f\nabla_a\nabla^a\phi \nabla^b\phi + \nabla_a\nabla^a\phi \nabla_f\nabla^b\phi + \nabla_f\nabla^a\phi \nabla_a\nabla^b\phi + \nabla^a\phi \nabla_f\nabla_a\nabla^b\phi)
\\&
-g_{ea} (\nabla_f\nabla_b\nabla^a\phi \nabla^b\phi +\nabla_b\nabla^a\phi \nabla_f\nabla^b\phi + \nabla_f\nabla^a\phi \nabla_b\nabla^b\phi + \nabla^a\phi \nabla_f\nabla_b\nabla^b\phi)
\\&
+g_{ae}g_{bf} g^{gh} (\nabla_g\nabla_h\nabla^a\phi \nabla^b\phi + \nabla_h\nabla^a\phi \nabla_g\nabla^b\phi +\nabla_g\nabla^a\phi \nabla_h\nabla^b\phi +\nabla^a\phi \nabla_g\nabla_h\nabla^b\phi)
\\&
+g_{ef} (\nabla_a\nabla_b\nabla^a\phi \nabla^b\phi + \nabla_b\nabla^a\phi \nabla_a\nabla^b\phi + \nabla_a\nabla^a\phi \nabla_b\nabla^b\phi + \nabla^a\phi \nabla_a\nabla_b\nabla^b\phi)
\Big\} \delta g^{ef}
\end{align*}
after I use integration by parts and omit boundary terms.
I am stuck because I don't know how to manipulate the terms with 3 covariant derivative to $\phi$. I know that
$$
(\nabla_c\nabla_d-\nabla_d\nabla_c )\nabla^a\phi=R^a_{~bcd} \nabla^b\phi,
$$
but I cannot find any other math identities in the literature.
Thank you for your time.
